# Type deduction given member function pointer with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, decltype

Assuming I have a member function pointer how I could write code that automatically deduce parameters for given template signature:

```
 template<typename T> class Foo {};

 template<typename R, typename C, typename... A>
 class Foo<R(C, A...)> { };
```

For C and R there is no problem as something similar to this does the trick:

```
template<typename R, typename C, typename... A> 
R deduce_R_type(R(C::*)(A...));

template<typename R, typename C, typename... A>
C deduce_C_type(R(C::*)(A...));
```

Then I can actually plug it in to the Foo instantiation but how to deduce the types coming from the variadic part of the template?

```
Foo<
decltype(deduce_R_type(&SomeClass::SomeFunction)) (
decltype(deduce_C_type(&SomeClass::SomeFunction)), ___ ??? ___)> instance
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need at least one helper and something like `std::tuple`:

```
template<typename R, typename C, typename... A>
std::tuple<A...> deduce_A_tuple(R(C::*)(A...));

template<typename R, typename C, typename T>
struct FooHelper;

template<typename R, typename C, typename... A>
struct FooHelper< R, C, std::tuple<A...> >
{
    typedef Foo< R( C, A... ) > type;
};
```

and then you can use:

```
FooHelper< decltype(deduce_R_type(&SomeClass::SomeFunction)),
           decltype(deduce_C_type(&SomeClass::SomeFunction)), 
           decltype(deduce_A_tuple(&SomeClass::SomeFunction)) >::type instance;
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08888a1cd627be05)

---

As user [DyP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683) pointed out it could be much simpler when you have to use a helper anyways:

```
template<typename>
struct FooHelper;

template<typename R, typename C, typename... A>
struct FooHelper< R (C::*)(A...) >
{
    using type = Foo< R( C, A... ) >;
};
```

and use it as

```
FooHelper< decltype(&SomeClass::SomeFunction) >::type instance;
```

Comment: Once you introduce a helper type, you only need to pass one argument to it. `template<class Func> FooHelper; template<class R, class C, class... A> FooHelper<R(C::*)(A...)> { using type = Foo<R(C,A...)>; }; using MyFoo = FooHelper<decltype(&SomeClass::SomeFunction)>::type;`

Comment: @DyP True. I tried to do minimalistic changes to what the OP had and apparently missed the obvious :)